# Ajax comments not working in Rails 3.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

In layouts/application.html.erb. I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Some title</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print', 'media' => 'print' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom', 'jquery.colorbox-min', 'jquery.corner', 'jquery.countdown.min', 'jquery.uploadFileThis',
    'jquery.ui.core', 'jquery.ui.mouse', 'jquery.ui.position', 'jquery.ui.slider', 'jquery.ui.widget', 'jquery.ui.datepicker',
    'ajaxupload', 'jwplayer', 'swfobject', 'flowplayer-3.2.4.min', 'rails', 
    'application', :cache => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>
.....
```

In my view, I have:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', song_comment_path(comment.media, comment), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :remote => true %>
```

My Comments controller, destroy method looks like:

```
  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(root_path) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
      format.js   {  }
    end
  end
```

When I click this link, I get a pop-up box saying "Are you sure?". I click OK. I have a destroy.js.erb file in /views/comments. Inside this file, I have:

```
alert('Inside destroy.js.erb');
// and some code to hide the comment element
```

The comment is deleted, but not via ajax. It seems, the link_to goes into comment controller, destroy method. But is responding to respond.html, instead of respond.js. Hence why I don't get the **alert('Inside destroy.js.erb');**

This all used to work fine when I was still using Rails 3.0.0, until I decided to upgrade:

- to Rails 3.0.3,
- from query 1.4.0 to 1.4.4 (http://jquery.com/),
- and update latest rails.js (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)

Why isn't format.js being called? Why is Rails still trying to call format.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the actual link generated by the `link_to`, you'll find that even though you're using ajax to send the delete request, you're still sending a request to `/song/:song_id/comment/:comment_id`. Because there's no format, Rails will default to `.html`.

To make sure the request goes to the right format, you can add a `:format` option to your link_to:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', song_comment_path(comment.media, comment, :format => :js), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :remote => true %>
```

This should now give you a link like this: `/song/:song_id/comment/:comment_id.js`

Comment: Comments in this jquery-ujs issue have further info: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/closed#issue/52

Comment: Providing :format => :js is a Rails 3.0.3 thing or a workaround for the issue at github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/closed#issue/52 ? Furthermore, the devs at github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/closed#issue/52 seem to be suggesting a patch. Has this patch been released yet?

Comment: What I also don't understand is. Why do we need to specify the ".js" extension? Shouldn't Rails be smart enough to figure out which format to respond to? Rails 3.0.0 didn't have any problems with this.. In addition, the url's look cleaner/neater without the .js extension, dont they?

Comment: How I understand it is that ajax request doesn't equal to js response format by default. Request accept headers specify the format of the response. If you make ajax request you might want to return html for example to be inserted to the page. Now, if the ajax request header is currently "*/*" then moving the "format.js {}" to the top should serve it first because ajax request accepts everything. Alternative is to use setRequestHeader for your ajax calls. I haven't tested this myself.

Comment: Heikki, so why am I having to set :format => :js for the first time? In Rails 3.0.0, I never had to set this. Was there something wrong with Rail 3.0.0? I just need to know if setting :format => :js is the proper way, or if this is a workaround.

Comment: @Christian: You have to specify the `.js` extension because Rails doesn't discriminate. In many cases, you might want to fetch html or json with Ajax--not just javascript. Rails will let you fetch whatever content in whatever format.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up vonconrad. One other solution I found was to have format.js before format.html in the respond_to block

Comment: Vonconrad, so I am assuming there was a problem with Rails 3.0.0 then? In 3.0.0, there was no need to be explicit

Comment: @Christian: I think the change was in jquery-ujs. There was a commit where setRequestHeader was added but now its reverted. Simply making a request with javascript (ajax) doesn't make it send javascript back. I myself really rarely have use for pure .js as a response. You can set the request header for the ajax calls if you want it to behave that way. Revert commit: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/commit/cff3fa97168cdac1f124395826bcdff967298f96#

Comment: Heikki, thanks for that. I see now, that older versions o jquery-ujs set the header for javascript, so rails can send a js response back. In the newer versions, since we need to define :format => :js in the link_to method. How do we do this with forms? Is it like this: <%= form_for([parent, @comment], :remote => true, :format => :js) do |f| %> ?

Comment: I think its clear that the problem is with jquery-ujs. Have a look at https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/issue/52/#issue/52/comment/619237 The current version does not allow us to override the header in "ajax:beforeSend"...

Comment: @Christian: Are you sure the override doesn't work? Revert commit that I mentioned is dated 5 days after that comment.

Comment: Heikki, in application.js, I have: jQuery.ajaxSetup({
   beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
 }), which is before $(document).ready. It does not seem to override

Comment: Ok, seems like the newer version of rails.js now seems to work as highlighted at https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/commit/fbbefa0773d791d3a67b7a3bb971c10ca750131b The following code now overrides appropriately: jQuery.ajaxSetup({ beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")} }). Great work from the author of the gem neerajdotname!